# timezones and saved timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

This is seriously breaking my brain, I can't even come up with a title that encapsulates what my question is, let me try and explain.

So I have a time logging page that takes time() and stores it in the data base. Now this page can be used in different states - in this example in Australia/Sydney and Australia/Brisbane. I can set the timezone and print out the right time.

But this is where I am getting confused, a timestamp is a timestamp, no matter if it is in Brisbane or Sydney - correct? And by setting the timezone, I can use the same timestamp to show me the actual time the timestamp was made in either Brisbane or Sydney.

Sydney is not always in daylight saving, so if reading the saved timestamp the converted time will be wrong? Am I barking up the wrong tree here and my logic has failed me? Am I meant to be saving timestamps differently ?

Comment: You can easily test this stuff.

Comment: maybe it would be a good idea to save your timestamps in GMT or UTC and have another field with the timezone offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function time() returns always timestamp that is timezone independent (UTC).  Timezones only come into play when you create a date object in PHP.  PHP applies whatever timezone is set in php.ini to the timestamp and makes it into a date corresponding to the timezone:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp(1171502725); // We just made a date in php.ini's timezone based on a UTC timestamp
```

Alternatively, you can tell PHP the timezone you want the date in and it will override whatever's in php.ini:

```
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney'));
```

When PHP makes the date object, internally it simply just adds (or subtracts) the timezone offset.

Comment: Okay that explains why I can set the timezone to either Sydney or Brisbane and 'time()' still gives me the same stamp. So I should be setting the timezone and using say 'date()' to come up with a string to save in the db?

Comment: No, save everything as UTC in the database otherwise you are going to have a bad time, especially if you are using a db column such as DATE or DATETIME.  For PHP's sake in being able to work out which timezone to display to the user, you are best to save the timezone string in the database against the user's account.  You can use that string to work out in which timezone to display dates in for that user.

Comment: Okay, this is exactly the bit that confuses me, so I use time() to give me the timestamp and save that in the db.

At this very moment there is no difference between Sydney and Brisbane times. so I set the time of the user to view times in Sydney, I take the saved timestamp and it the log will be right, but down the track from now Sydney jumps an hour ahead, if I take the same saved timestamp then it will display the time an hour out?

Is this where verhie's idea of saving the offest at the time with the record, is needed?

Comment: I don't think I have a full picture of your requirements.  Is this  for a log entry and you want to display it to a user in the future in the UTC offset at the time it was logged? If so, it would depend on what you want to do with the timestamp which might influence how you store it.  If you only need to print it on the screen, you might consider saving it in text format as you described, however if you want to sort it or compare it with another timestamp at any stage for example, you will need to store it as a number along with the UTC offset (which factors DST at the time of the event)

Comment: Yep, your second part is the way to go, by saving the timestamp as UTC and also including the offset at the time, later down the track I can display the right time as I will know the offset to the UTC and I will still be able to perform tasks, like your example of comparing etc.